# Spring does not use annotated constructor (@JsonCreator) for instantiation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using Spring 4.1.1 with JavaConfig and Jackson 2.4.3.

My controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
public interface PatientWebService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/patients", method = POST)
    PatientResource createPatient(@RequestBody PatientResource resource);
}
```

The json I am sending looks like this:

```
{
    "firstName": "Max",
    "lastName": "Mustermann",
    "birthDate": "1964-04-14",
    "sex": "MAN"
}
```

and I want it to be parsed into this class:

```
package at.landsteiner.patient.web;

import at.landsteiner.patient.Patient;
import at.landsteiner.patient.Sex;
import at.landsteiner.web.EntityResource;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class PatientResource extends EntityResource {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    private Sex sex;

    @JsonCreator
    public PatientResource(@JsonProperty("firstName") String firstName, @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName, @JsonProperty("birthDate") LocalDate birthDate, @JsonProperty("sex") Sex sex) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    // getter
}
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
19:43:41,842 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 19:43:41 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet.doService - DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/questionnaire-api/patients]
19:43:41,846 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 19:43:41 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal - Looking up handler method for path /patients
19:43:41,850 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 19:43:41 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal - Returning handler method [public at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientWebServiceImpl.createPatient(at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource)]
19:43:41,850 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 19:43:41 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'patientWebServiceImpl'
19:43:41,868 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 19:43:41 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException - Resolving exception from handler [public at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientWebServiceImpl.createPatient(at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource)]: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource.<init>()
19:43:41,869 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 19:43:41 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver.resolveException - Resolving exception from handler [public at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientWebServiceImpl.createPatient(at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource)]: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource.<init>()
19:43:41,870 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 19:43:41 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException - Resolving exception from handler [public at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientWebServiceImpl.createPatient(at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource)]: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource.<init>()
19:43:41,878 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 19:43:41 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet.processRequest - Could not complete request
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource.<init>()
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:107) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:79) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,879 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) [wildfly-undertow-8.1.0.Final.jar!/:8.1.0.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) [wildfly-undertow-8.1.0.Final.jar!/:8.1.0.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,882 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,883 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,883 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,883 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,883 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,883 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,883 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar!/:1.0.15.Final]
19:43:41,883 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0]
19:43:41,883 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0]
19:43:41,883 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.8.0]
19:43:41,884 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: at.landsteiner.patient.web.PatientResource.<init>()
19:43:41,884 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971) ~[na:1.8.0]
19:43:41,884 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2165) ~[na:1.8.0]
19:43:41,884 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
19:43:41,884 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

How do I configure Spring to delegate the instantiation to Jackson?
Is it even possible to combine the use of `@JsonCreator` with `@RequestBody`?

My JavaConfig looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "at.landsteiner" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(converter());
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.registerModule(new JSR310Module());
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a completely different error. It makes no sense that it would try to get the parameterless constructor of your class. Are you sure you are showing us the exact classes and error?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. Because if I add a parameterless constructor, the error disappears, but then the object is empty. 
From the stacktrace I can tell that spring tries to instantiate the bean itself and therefore does not care about the `@JsonCreator` annotation.

Comment: I have added the part of the stacktrace where I says, default constructor not found. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Can you turn the logging level up to DEBUG and post the ouput of the logs when you post the specified JSON to the controller?

Comment: Is there a controller implementation?

Comment: Yes there is a controller implementation.
I turned the logging level for `org.springframework` to DEBUG but there are (surprisingly) hardly any messages.
I replaced the stacktrace with the complete output after issuing the request.

Comment: Are you sure the annoations `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` are imported from `com.fasterxml.****`?

Comment: Yes, I updated the code in the question to include the import statements.

Comment: Thanks for that! Could you also show the logging output of `com.fasterxml` when it's level is set to DEBUG? I have a feeling that `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is not being called at all, but I may be wrong

Comment: I already have that in my logger configuration. It is not printing anything :/  
The converter is in the list of the message converters, but it is at the end and I think spring acts greedy here, if I remember corretly.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `createPatient` method to the implementation of the controller instead of the interface? I am not entirely sure that Spring would look for the `@RequestBody` in the interface

Comment: I have not tried that in this project, but I am using annotations in interface in a different project. That one is configured with xml though, don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: You were right. Spring needs the implementation annotated with a stereotype annotation in order to pick it up on classpath scanning. Therefore also the annotations need to go to the implementation, I did that and it is working now. I still wonder though how I managed to set it up in my other project to work with annotations on interfaces.
Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I did not test with Spring 4.1.1 (but did with Spring 4.0.5), I found that the problem is that the annotation `@RequestBody` is only present in the interface.

Spring will not look at the annotation of the method argument from the interface (not even sure if that's possible), but only from the concrete implementation.

Because of the missing annotation on the concrete implementation, Spring does attempt to use Jackson at all for instantiating the object, but uses the regular bean method.

If you simply add the annotation the argument of the concrete method as well, everything will work just fine